# Beginner C#. Making a random damage in Console

Tags: console-application

Me and a friend of mine are making a small little fun game that opens up in the command prompt. We are having trouble getting the random damage per turn to work. Per turn the damage does not change. We you like to have it when every time you attack the damage is different, because at this moment the first number generated for the damage stays the same till the game has ended. If there is anything else that you see that could be better feel free to add your option! Thank you for taking your time to read this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int playerHP = 30;
        int playerDMG = rand.Next(1, 8);
        string yourName;

        int monsterHP = 30;
        int monsterDMG = rand.Next(1, 10);

        string[] monsterName = { "John Crawford", "Gaurav the Chicken" , "Satan" , "Temmo"};
        string[] phrase = { " ' Let the blood drip from your body!'" , " Evil comes from the soul!" , " I will eat your soul!"};
        int phrasewords = rand.Next(0, phrase.Length);
        int mNames = rand.Next(0, monsterName.Length);

        //Story

        Console.WriteLine("Name your Hero: ");
        yourName = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("As you walk through the forest... " + monsterName[mNames] + " appears from the shadows \nand says," + phrase[phrasewords] + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to <attack> " + monsterName[mNames] + ", <defend> yourself, or <run>?\n");
        Console.ResetColor();

        while (playerHP > 0 && monsterHP > 0)
        {
            bool defend = false;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            //Inputs

            switch (input)
            {
                case "attack":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine(yourName + " attacks " + monsterName[mNames] + " with his fist, which deals " + playerDMG + " damage\n");
                    monsterHP -= playerDMG;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

                case "run":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " says, 'LOL NOPE' and you must remain on the battlefield.\n");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

                case "defend":
                    defend = true;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                    Console.WriteLine(yourName + " blocks " + monsterName[mNames] + "'s attack with his arms\n");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

            }

            //Damage & Health

            if (!defend)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " attacks " + yourName + " for " + monsterDMG + " damage because " + yourName + " doesn't know how to \ndefend himself.\n");
                playerHP -= monsterDMG;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " attacks " + yourName + " for " + (monsterDMG / 2) + " damage because " + yourName + " doesn't know how to \nfight like a man.\n");
                playerHP -= monsterDMG / 2;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(yourName + " has " + playerHP + " health.\n");
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " has " + monsterHP + " health.\n");

        }

        //Win, Lose, Tie

        if (playerHP <= 0)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(yourName + " died! GG NO RE\n");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        if (monsterHP <= 0 && (playerHP > 0))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Wow, you win. Congratulations.\n");
            Console.ResetColor();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.WriteLine("It was a tie!");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MonsterDMG and playeyDMG is only computed once.
Just move it to your loop : )

```
while (playerHP > 0 && monsterHP > 0)
    {
        bool defend = false;
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        monsterDMG = rand.Next(1, 10); //for example here
        playerDMG = rand.Next(1, 8); // : )
```

PS. Tip for the future: if you'll have to generate more randoms in short amount of time use this random generator : )

```
Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: If it helps, mark this answer as accepted. StackOverflow unanswered-answers-counter will help you ; ) Me too, Sir :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the new MonsterDMG and the PlayerDMG at the end of the while loop

```
int playerHP = 30;
        int playerDMG = rand.Next(1, 8);
        string yourName;

        int monsterHP = 30;
        int monsterDMG = rand.Next(1, 10);

        string[] monsterName = { "John Crawford", "Gaurav the Chicken" , "Satan" , "Temmo"};
        string[] phrase = { " ' Let the blood drip from your body!'" , " Evil comes from the soul!" , " I will eat your soul!"};
        int phrasewords = rand.Next(0, phrase.Length);
        int mNames = rand.Next(0, monsterName.Length);

        //Story

        Console.WriteLine("Name your Hero: ");
        yourName = Console.ReadLine();


        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("As you walk through the forest... " + monsterName[mNames] + " appears from the shadows \nand says," + phrase[phrasewords] + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to <attack> " + monsterName[mNames] + ", <defend> yourself, or <run>?\n");
        Console.ResetColor();

        while (playerHP > 0 && monsterHP > 0)
        {
            bool defend = false;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            //Inputs

            switch (input)
            {
                case "attack":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine(yourName + " attacks " + monsterName[mNames] + " with his fist, which deals " + playerDMG + " damage\n");
                    monsterHP -= playerDMG;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

                case "run":
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " says, 'LOL NOPE' and you must remain on the battlefield.\n");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

                case "defend":
                    defend = true;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                    Console.WriteLine(yourName + " blocks " + monsterName[mNames] + "'s attack with his arms\n");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    break;

            }

            //Damage & Health

            if (!defend)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " attacks " + yourName + " for " + monsterDMG + " damage because " + yourName + " doesn't know how to \ndefend himself.\n");
                playerHP -= monsterDMG;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " attacks " + yourName + " for " + (monsterDMG / 2) + " damage because " + yourName + " doesn't know how to \nfight like a man.\n");
                playerHP -= monsterDMG / 2;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(yourName + " has " + playerHP + " health.\n");
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName[mNames] + " has " + monsterHP + " health.\n");

            **playerDMG = rand.Next(1, 8);
            monsterDMG = rand.Next(1, 10);**
        }

        //Win, Lose, Tie

        if (playerHP <= 0)
        {
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(yourName + " died! GG NO RE\n");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        if (monsterHP <= 0 && (playerHP > 0))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Wow, you win. Congratulations.\n");
            Console.ResetColor();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            Console.WriteLine("It was a tie!");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```